# Сериализация сложного JAVA объекта в JSON

Tags: java, json, сериализация

Добрый день подскажите как сериализовать в JSON объект Files? Используя метод toJsonString сериализуются только поле nameDirectory, а поле pool выводится в виде хеша?

```
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class Files {

    public Map<String, File> pool;

    public String nameDirectory;

    public String toJsonString(){
        JSONObject JSobj = new JSONObject(pool);
        JSobj.toJSONString();
    }
}

public class File {
    String PathFile;
    ArrayList<Record> Records;
    boolean PutInEnd;
}

public class Record {

    private String recordname;
    private String status;
    private int countExecution;
}
```

Comment: Есть супер-простая библиотека, jodd json, которая умеет именно то, что вам нужно. Про [jodd json можно почитать тут](https://jodd.org/json/), подробнее про [сериалайзер](https://jodd.org/json/json-serializer.html) и [парсер](https://jodd.org/json/json-parser.html) (не забудьте ".deep(true)", иначе он НЕ сериализует коллекции). Для вашего примера: `    public String toJsonString(){ return (new jodd.json.JsonSerializer()).deep(true).serialize(pool); }`

Comment: @Sanya_Zol оформите ваш камент в виде ответа - крайне интересный камент

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для таких целей есть специальные библиотеки - [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) и [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;

class Record {
    // Поле name и так находится в Record,
    // называть его recordname - это лишнее
    private String name;
    private String status;
    private int executionCount;

    public Record() {}

    public Record(String name, String status, int executionCount) {
        setName(name);
        setStatus(status);
        setExecutionCount(executionCount);
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setExecutionCount(int executionCount) {
        this.executionCount = executionCount;
    }

    public int getExecutionCount() {
        return executionCount;
    }
}

// Плохая идея использовать имена классов
// входящих в стандартную библиотеку
class SomeFile {
    private String path;
    // Имена полей должны начинаться со строчной буквы
    private List<Record> records;
    private boolean putInEnd;

    public SomeFile() {
        records = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public SomeFile(String path, boolean putInEnd) {
        this();
        setPath(path);
        setPutInEnd(putInEnd);
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPutInEnd(boolean putInEnd) {
        this.putInEnd = putInEnd;
    }

    public void addRecord(Record record) {
        records.add(record);
    }

    public List<Record> getRecords() {
        return records;
    }
}

class SomeFiles {
    private String name;
    private Map<String, SomeFile> pool;

    public SomeFiles() {
        pool = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public SomeFiles(String name) {
        this();
        setName(name);
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void putSomeFile(String name, SomeFile someFile) {
        pool.put(name, someFile);
    }

    public Map<String, SomeFile> getPool() {
        return pool;
    }
}

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeFile f = new SomeFile("/root/secret.txt", false);
        f.addRecord(new Record("Some Record", "Some status", 42));
        f.addRecord(new Record("Another Record", "Same status", 0));

        SomeFiles sf = new SomeFiles("Some Files");
        sf.putSomeFile("Some File", f);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // Для вывода с отступами
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

        try {
            // Здесь происходит самая главная магия
            mapper.writeValue(new File("some_files.json"), sf);
        }
        catch(JsonGenerationException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(JsonMappingException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Получится такое:

```
{
  "name" : "Some Files",
  "pool" : {
    "Some File" : {
      "path" : "/root/secret.txt",
      "records" : [ {
        "name" : "Some Record",
        "status" : "Some status",
        "executionCount" : 42
      }, {
        "name" : "Another Record",
        "status" : "Same status",
        "executionCount" : 0
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: огромное спасибо, все работает!

Answer (score 1):

У вас 2 проблемы:

1. Сериализация `Map<String, File>`
2. Сериализация `File`

Если с первой более-менее все понятно - в рамках Gson решается приблизительно так:

```
Map<String, File> myMap;
Type typeOfMap = new TypeToken<Map<String, File>>() { }.getType();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
String json = gson.toJson(myMap, typeOfMap);
```

Вторая проблема более концептуальная что-ли. Никто кроме вас не понимает, что вы имеете ввиду под сериализацией объекта типа `File`: или вы захотите просто сериализовать имя файла или имя файла включая полный путь или универсальный `URI` или же вообще содержимое файла. На этот вопрос кроме вас никто не ответит.

Чтобы оформить свое отношение к сериализации объекта типа `File` вам нужно написать свой собственный сериалайзер - в терминах GSon это выглядит примерно так:

```
public class MyFileAdapter implements JsonSerializer<File> {
    @Override
     public JsonElement serialize(File src, Type typeOfSrc,
                JsonSerializationContext context) {
             //blah-blah
        }
    }
}
```

Далее надо известить Gson о том, что отныне объекты типа `File` будут обрабатываться вашим адаптером:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(File.class, new MyFileAdapter());
```

Comment: У него файл - это собственный класс.

Comment: Еще надо написать десериализатор....